# assistance with lua code in a wow

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

heres the problem 
 [error T_T](http://pastebin.com/E4YWUESU)

its telling me that i have this problem cant figure it out. any help is appreciated 
also not that great with lua but willing to try my best to figure it out. im try to rez this old addon which i really liked

okay heres that full "core.lua"

it is basically a addon for wow that talks and reponds (mostly yes / no questions)
i think its getting this error because, i read somewhere that they took arg1 out, so im not sure what to put there. might take it to a different website, just wasnt sure where to post it at first. i will go to  wowace, wowprogramming.com and post there

[pastebin(core.lua)](http://pastebin.com/yPeQd7Z1)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question as it stands now is not too useful, as it lacks the proper context. It seems from the error message that the variable `arg1` is `nil` when executing the code (although that is already partly speculation, since you did not provide much info). However, it is impossible to tell from your description where that variable came from and who was supposed to set its value. We are best at answering well specified, self-contained questions. We are not that good at debugging your code for you.

Comment: And which line is the line 616? This code sample is too localized.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete line 608 :)

When started addon register a wisp event, and does not give parameters... If it is just a mistake or something, it'll work, but i can't just recode all of it =) Try to contact :

> Stewart (01satkins@gmail.com)  http://www.stewartatkins.org/

As said in code =)

Comment: thanks, after deleting it didnt come up with any errors. but the addon did not work, so i added back that line. deleted `(arg6~="GM" or self.db.profile.gm) and ` now it comes up with

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4P04LJpK is the error ^ (previous comment)
edited lua took out the GM arg6 as i dont seem to need it at this stage anyway~ http://pastebin.com/2Cn0vw3r

Comment: I don't really understand what this addon is doing, but try to replace ai_set[arg2] by ai_set[self.db.profile.prefix] at lines 618,619,620. arg2 is upposed to be a character name wich symbolize the bot, i believe self.db.profile.prefix contains it, but if it does not work just put ai_set["test"] instead.